# Padding on navbar making it overflow from page, inner container with margin/padding doesn't work either

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a new website from scratch, and I'm already stuck on the navbar. I have this simple HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="page-title">SkillUp</div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <!-- PAGE CONTENT INJECTED HERE -->
  <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #197719;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.page-title{
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Lobster, cursive;
  font-size: 54px;
  text-shadow: -3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Simple. But the navbar, when padding is added, extends past the page horizontally by the size of the padding times 2. I've tried everything from setting the body and html width to 100%, to putting another div inside the navbar and setting its width to 100% and adding padding to it, but that also makes the outer navbar bigger! It only works when I remove padding from the navbar, but I didn't have this problem with other websites I've made! I don't want to have to put margins the inner elements for it to work.

Here's a picture of what happens:

[Annoying navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNDP5.png)

Help, please! Thanks!

Comment: try to remove `width: 100%` and use instead `top:0; left:0; right:0` so the navbar will extend itself to fit 100%

Comment: @shall That worked too! So do you guys think it's better to do that, or box-sizing: border-box;? In terms of compatibility or whatever.

Comment: I believe there's no difference, box-sizing is full compatible, check it [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the .navbar selector.

Comment: Didn't know that trick. I would have nested a flexbox inside a full width container... Nice one

Comment: @GolezTrol No man, with your solution, the title doesn't take up all the space...

Comment: I love you. But might this cause problems in older browsers?